# convert jpg to avi vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I try to convert my sequenced numbers photos jpg to output.mp4 or avi
but my output file is empty 
the photos are renamed liked this out01.jpg , out02.jpg, etc. i have 10 frames (Photos)
I have try with this code:

```
Dim desk = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim args As String 'declare args
    'args = " -i C:\mediapubisert\out%03d.jpg -r 10 C:\mediapubisert\out.mp4 "
    args = " -i C:\mediapubisert\out%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\mediapubisert\out.mp4 "
    Dim proc As New Process
    Dim proci As New ProcessStartInfo
    proci.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ffmpeg.exe"
    proci.Arguments = args
    proci.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proci.CreateNoWindow = True
    proci.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo = proci
    proc.Start()
    Do Until proc.HasExited = True
        Me.Text = "Saving"
    Loop
    Me.Text = "your video done"
    'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(TextBox1.Text, DestPath + TextBox1.Text)
    MsgBox("Done")
    Dim directoryName As String = "C:\mediapubisert\"
```

Comment: personally I would forget about VB.NET for a minute and get it working directly from the command line first

Comment: @ADyson well i just deed what you have say , and now i know its beacuse the name out%02d some thing its wrong with the % and d wen i take out its do the video with one frame only

Comment: @ADyson i used like this ffmpeg.exe -i C:\mediapubisert\out01.jpg -r 10 C:\mediapubisert\out.mp4

Comment: using `%3` in place of the numbers in the filename seems to be the example used elsewhere. You seem to have randomly shoved a % in there without obvious purpose. I have no direct experience of this but a quick google shows that as a common pattern. Not sure if it works in Windows or not though, or just Unix-derived systems.

Comment: @bluemoonodd The `ffmpeg` command you are using in your code is different than the `ffmpeg` command you are trying in cli. The cli command will only make one frame output because you are only inputting one frame. In cli try `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i C:\mediapubisert\out%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\mediapubisert\out.mp4` and once you verify it works then try to get it to work in the code.

Comment: @bluemoonodd I changed your command so `-framerate 30` is used as an input option: otherwise the default of `-framerate 25` will be used and frames will be duplicated to reach `-r 30`. Applying the frame rate to the input will avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i start explaining each and every term related to this topic, i may run out of letters...  :(

Anyway, here's a simple code snippet to get started.Make sure you [download this](https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages/Accord.Extensions.Imaging.IO?groupby=Version) :)

```
Private Sub createAVideo(ByVal imageInputfolderName As String, ByVal outVideoFileName As String, ByVal Optional fps As Single = 12F, ByVal Optional imgSearchPattern As String = "*.png")
Dim vwriter As VideoWriter = New VideoWriter(outVideoFileName, New Accord.Extensions.Size(500, 500), fps, True) 'Make sure to change 500 with required height and width
Dim ReadImg As Accord.Extensions.Imaging.ImageDirectoryReader = New ImageDirectoryReader(imageInputfolderName, imgSearchPattern)
While ReadImg.Position < ReadImg.Length
    Dim i As IImage = ReadImg.Read()
    vwriter.Write(i)
End While

vwriter.Close()
End Sub
```

I never tried this myself but once heard about this library on SO , hope his helps :)

Comment: New VideoWriter(outVideoFileName, New Accord.Extensions.Size(500, 500), fps, True) 'Make sure to change 500 with required height and width

Comment: imports of type accord.extention.size failed